# jQuery - add icon to select option based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am currently trying to make any use of Polylang, a Wordpress plugin that allows to add language switcher to the website.

It currently generates simple select dropdown menu and changes the language upon selecting the language, so it's ok, however I am unable to style it properly - it's a raw dropdown menu.

I would like to add icons next to the displayed option, and as far as I know jQuery is my best shot here.

The issue I am having is that `<option>` tags are missing `id` or `class` tags, and it is impossible to add them without modifying the plugin itself.

Is it possible to create a jquery script that will display a flag next to the option based on it's `value` attribute?

Can you show me any example how to?

```
<select name="lang_choice" id="lang_choice">
<option value="en">English</option>
<option value="fr" selected="selected">French</option>
<option value="de">Deutsch</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If I'm correct, you can't style options in standard `<select>`. What you can definitely do is to create your own wrap of `<select>` (based on `<div>`s or whatever else) or to use plugin that will do it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLUTION 1 (Flags outside of the dropdown):

Try this:

```
$('<img class=flagicon src="'+$("select#lang_choice").val()+'.png">').insertAfter("#lang_choice");
$("select#lang_choice").change(function(){
    $(".flagicon").attr("src", $("select#lang_choice").val()+'.png');
});
```

The function assumes, that you have your flags named fr.png, de.png and en.png
The first line adds the first icon, if no option has changed yet.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2j46orr4/1/

SOLUTION 2 (Flags inside the dropdown, every option has its own background-image):
If you want to show the flag INSIDE the option, use a background-image:

CSS:

```
#lang_choice {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(/img/en.png);
    background-position: right center;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
#lang_choice option:nth-child(1) {
    background: url(/img/en.png) no-repeat right center;  
}
#lang_choice option:nth-child(2) {
    background: url(/img/fr.png) no-repeat right center;  
}
#lang_choice option:nth-child(3) {
    background: url(/img/de.png) no-repeat right center;  
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("select#lang_choice").css("background-image",'url(/img/'+$("select#lang_choice").val()+'.png)');
$("select#lang_choice").change(function(){
    $("select#lang_choice").css("background-image",'url(/img/'+$("select#lang_choice").val()+'.png)');
});
```

The flags have 16px margin on their right, so they are not hidden under the option arrow.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2j46orr4/7/
(Chrome does not seem to render the option > background-image at the moment.)

Comment: It seems to add an icon outside of the dropdown. I want to display flags inside the dropdown.

Comment: That's a big step forward! However, when you view the list, only text is displayed. How to make it display all the flags next to names when you click on the dropdown?

Comment: That's the whole trick. I can't modify the existing html code since it's printed through PHP script, that can't be modified either. It needs to be done with use of javascript.

Comment: It works good in Firefox. Chrome does not show flags, and when it comes to IE...well, I can live with IE being messed up. Any idea why Chrome behaves like that?

Comment: Chrome's Developer Tools say the image attribute is set. So maybe chrome does not render option->background-image. The first version with the flag outside of the dropdown works in chrome, though, maybe you can use this.

Comment: hint: if the answer solves your question, you may gracefully accept it;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a jquery plugin like this one.

HERE: http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick#demo

Comment: ddSlick does not work with IE7 and has minor issues with IE8, and on top of that I can't figure out how can I make it work with just `value` fields.

Comment: @AndyAndy, for your first issue (IE7), if anyone still uses IE7 then they shouldn't even be allowed to use the internet until they upgrade their browser as we are in 2015 (almost). as for your second issue (IE8) i have never had any issues with IE8 using this plugin. as for your third issue, you ned to learn how to use the plugin.